# plotting a rectangle and set of points together in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am a complete newbie to matlab....As of now I am experimenting with stuff.I wanted to plot a set of points together with a rectangle in matlab.One of my friends told me the following piece of code...It seems to be wrong

```
clear all; close all;clc;
data = cell2mat({1,1;2,2;3,3;4,4;5,5;6,6;});
xx=data(:,1);
yy=data(:,2);
hand=plot(xx,yy,'r.',Rectangle('Position',[1,1,2,2]));xmin=min(xx);xmax=max(xx);ymin=min(yy);ymax=max(yy);
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax]);
axis('square');set(hand, 'MarkerSize', 1);
```

The plot command seems to fail...What is the correction I have to make???

Comment: How do you know it fails, do you get an error and if so which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot points, hold on additional plots, then plot rectangle:

```
hand = plot(xx,yy,'r.'); 
hold on 
rectangle('Position',[1,1,2,2]);
```